# Angular directive works in browser window, need to make it work in sized div with overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

**The good:**
I found a wonderful directive for sticky headers that I would like to use. I've put the directive in my `app.js` file. It works fine when the markup is within the the `<body>` tag. I checked the console, and it's clear. If I inspect element, it's doing the job.

**The problem:**
However, there are issues when I place the markup within a div that has a set height and an `overflow:auto`. The directive still works in that it casts the sticky headers, but the headers stop sticking.

I think it's because the directive is set to recognize the browser window: `$window`. Is there a way to set the `$window` to the actual element? My parent element is `<div class="left-block">`.

Here is a link to the directive: [Sticky Header - Angular Directive](http://codepen.io/DDN-Shep/pen/RNjPqe)

I'd like to have the directive stick the headers to the top of it's container div. Is this possible?

```html
<body class="demo" ng-app="ddnApp">

  <div class="left-block">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
      <ddn-sticky-wrapper>
        <div>Header {{ i }}</div>
      </ddn-sticky-wrapper>
      <div class="whitespace"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Here is the directive:

```html
angular
  .module('ddnApp', [])
  .directive('ddnStickyWrapper', ['$window', function($window) {
    var stickies = [],
        scroll = function scroll() {
          angular.forEach(stickies, function($sticky, index) {
            var sticky = $sticky[0],
                pos = $sticky.data('pos');
            
            if (pos <= $window.pageYOffset) {
              var $next = stickies[index + 1],
                  next = $next ? $next[0] : null,
                  npos = $next.data('pos');

              $sticky.addClass("fixed");

              if (next && next.offsetTop >= npos - next.clientHeight)
                $sticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", npos - sticky.clientHeight + 'px');
            } else {
              var $prev = stickies[index - 1],
                  prev = $prev ? $prev[0] : null;

              $sticky.removeClass("fixed");

              if (prev && $window.pageYOffset <= pos - prev.clientHeight)
                $prev.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
            }
          });
        },
        compile = function compile(element, attrs, transclude) {
          return function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var sticky = element.children()[0],
                $sticky = angular.element(sticky);

            element.css('height', sticky.clientHeight + 'px');

            $sticky.data('pos', sticky.offsetTop);
            stickies.push($sticky);
          }
        },
        link = function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var sticky = element.children()[0],
                $sticky = angular.element(sticky);

            element.css('height', sticky.clientHeight + 'px');

            $sticky.data('pos', sticky.offsetTop);
            stickies.push($sticky);
          };

    angular.element($window).off('scroll', scroll).on('scroll', scroll);
    
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<ddn-sticky ng-transclude></ddn-sticky>',
      link: link
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: You can inject `$element` instead of `$window` but I dont think that would work, hmm...

Comment: Replace all instances of $window with $element?

Comment: It looks like the directive is using `pageYOffset` which is an alias for `scrollY` which is not available on divs. You could try replacing all instances of `$window` with `$element` and `pageYOffset`  with `scrollTop`. I don't have any way to test it right now though so I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Can I try this in the CodePen? Here's a link to the directive: [Sticky Header - Angular Directive](http://codepen.io/DDN-Shep/pen/RNjPqe)

Comment: I like the effect too. 
I'd like it to do the same but within a container div.

Comment: Well.. I tried my best. I removed the multiple header functionality because it was giving me problems and made it work with one element. You can see it here... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RraBMr I didn't have time to look at multiple headers but I dont think it would be too hard to re-add

Comment: Thanks for trying, I had no idea you'd go to all that effort. I appreciate it.